# Css is not being applied properly when I uploaded files to github while it was working well on local. what could be the reason?

Tags: css

The "find out more" button should be in center while it was on left. It ran perfectly on local but not working properly after uploading it to GitHub.

Here are the files:
[Link to Github](https://github.com/rahul97kumar/rahul97kumar.github.io)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it *was* working on your computer, but you need to center it instead of using a 5% margin.

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto; /* Center it by making the margin auto */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. It is related to the button. You can see for yourself running it in local it's all in the center. Github link which is this rahul97kumar.github.io is applying the CSS improperly, not what I am getting in local.

Comment: i did see it myself. there is nothing in your current css to center the button. giving it a 5% margin will only make it look centered on a certain sized device. if you changed it and didn't see a difference then you need to clear your cache. this is the correct answer, i promise.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use absolute value with negative pixel amount. Use something like float: left (or bring in a css library and utilize that)

Comment: Thank you for answering but it doesn't work. I am expecting the result to be what I am getting on local not on rahul97kumar.github.io which is the GitHub link.